# Python program with selenium(webdriver) Don't Work as single and noconsole exe file (pyinstaller)

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, pyinstaller

The following is my python code:

```
## t.py ##

from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver

def clicked():
    iedriver = "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IEDriverServer.exe"
    try:        
        driver=webdriver.Ie(iedriver)        
    except Exception as e:        
        messagebox.showerror("Error",e)
    driver.get('www.baidu.com')  
Top=Tk()
Button(Top,text='Click Me',command=clicked).pack()
Top.mainloop()
```

This works fine, but when I convert this to a single .exe file with PyInstaller(t.spec):

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['D:\\program\\Python\\t.py'],
         pathex=['D:\\program\\Python'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=None,
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=None,
         runtime_hooks=None,
         excludes=None,
         win_no_prefer_redirects=None,
         win_private_assemblies=None,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,       
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='t',
      debug=False,
      strip=None,
      upx=False,
      console=0 , icon='D:\\program\\Python\\logo\\t.ico')
```

It will prompt the following error when clicking the button to run:
[Seems that IEDriver executable can't be recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1tiH.jpg)

When I change the option "console=0" to "console=1" in the spec file, IE can be run after clicking the button. Any idea why IE can't be run when "console=0" is set?

Comment: Have you tried adding `C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer` on the PATH environment variable before running it?

Comment: Yes, my PATH as below, but still can't fix this issue:
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windo
ws\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Python34;"C:\Pro
gram Files\Internet Explorer"

Comment: In your last comment, there is a space between "pro" and "gram" is that a typo in your comment?

Comment: Yes, it is a typo for my mistake, but it is correct in my system path and this can't fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I fixed this by modifying the *Service class* in selenium package. I'm not sure whether this is a bug for selenium(2.47.3). The original code is only redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` but not `stdin` when it calls `subprocess.Popen` function.

I modified the code from:

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

To:

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE,
                stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Then the issue is gone.

Comment: new method here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639052/pyinstaller-one-file-no-console-does-not-work-fatal-error