# Failed to execute script: Why I am getting Fatal Error when adding --noconsole in pyinstaller command

Tags: python, tkinter, build, package, pyinstaller

Failed to execute script: Why I am getting Fatal Error when adding `--noconsole` in `pyinstaller` command [Python3.8]

Note: command to build the exe

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --noconsole --icon "C:/_myPython/build/app.ico"  "C:/_myPython/build/kg.py"
```

Note: Purpose of this code: To get macaddress and display
Note: kg.py script

```
import re, uuid
import subprocess
import time
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import random


ipconfig_all = subprocess.check_output('ipconfig /all').decode()
mac_addr_pattern = re.compile(r'(?:[0-9a-fA-F]-?){12}')
mac_addr_list = re.findall(mac_addr_pattern, ipconfig_all)



root= tk.Tk()
root.title("Title")

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 380, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()
 
headtxt = tk.Label(root, text="Title", fg='black', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(175, 30, window=headtxt)

footertxt = tk.Label(root, text="Footer text", fg='gray', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(175, 275, window=footertxt)
 
def getKey ():
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text= mac_addr_list[0]+'F-'+mac_addr_list[3], fg='black', font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(180, 150, window=label1)
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='<  Show Key  >',command=getKey, bg='black',fg='white')
canvas1.create_window(175, 100, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: instead of noconsole flag try using -w

Comment: i tried -w and error still the same.

Comment: okay so now remove the no console flag and try in console, by saying -c and then you will see what is causing the error(printed in the console) and u can just copy and paste that error code to the Q or even try fixing it on your own

Comment: There is no error in the console. Only an alert window saying "Failed to execute script"

Comment: that is strange, without an errorcode displayed in the console, there wudnt be an error in d code and it wont fail to execute, and also if u choose `-c` flag, then der wont b a window saying failed to execute script, instead there wll just be a console

Comment: your code for pyinstaller should something like `pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile -c --icon "C:/_myPython/build/app.ico"  "C:/_myPython/build/kg.py"`

Comment: I tried this pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile -c --icon "C:/_myPython/build/app.ico"  "C:/_myPython/build/kg.py" and still no luck. My python file is not inside "build" folder but I tried to copy the .py inside and still doesn't work.

Comment: when console pops up, what does it show in it and note that u have to copy the exe file to the main directory (out of build folder)

Comment: subprocess stdin redirect may not be possible in windowed mode, that may be giving fatal error, fix example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33888465/3999721